# Extended Traits in Collections

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have a plain trait `Fruit` and an extended trait `WeightedFruit`. The Rust compiler accepts the `Fruit` trait in a `LinkedList` but not `WeightedFruit` in `BTreeSet`. What should be changed to make the sorted set work?

```
pub trait Fruit { }

pub trait WeightedFruit: Fruit + Ord { }

pub fn main() {
    let unsorted: LinkedList<Box<Fruit>> = LinkedList::new();
    let sorted: BTreeSet<Box<WeightedFruit>> = BTreeSet::new();
}
```

The error messages are:

```
the trait `WeightedFruit` cannot be made into an object
trait `WeightedFruit: std::cmp::Ord` not satisfied
...
```

Comment: You can't really use `Ord` with trait objects, as it can only compare concrete objects of the same type (I can't resist saying you can't compare `Apple`s and `Orange`s). Do you need to store multiple different `Fruit`s in one container? I'd try `impl Ord for Box<WeightedFruit>` (and Eq), but I haven't got time right now. If this is still open tomorrow I'll have a play.

Comment: How is this different from other existing questions with the same error message ("the trait ... cannot be made into an object")?

Comment: I really couldn't find an existing question which could explain why you seem to be able to use traits as objects in some cases but not in some others (the Linkedlist part above compiles). And yeah, my intention was to compare apples and oranges... :-) OO languages wouldn't have any problems on that.

Comment: OO languages have similar kind of problem: For example in Java you can reimplement `compareTo` method, but then you have to dynamically check if you actually got an object of a type that you are able to compare. If you go the typed way and implement the `Comparable<T>` interface, you must choose the `T`. The `Ord` in rust is like `Comparable<T>` in Java, but you can not choose the `T`, it is always `Self`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pub trait WeightedFruit: Fruit + Ord { }
```

This says the every struct that implements `WeightedFruit` must be comparable to itself. But not to other structs that implement that trait. So if an `Apple` implements `WeightedFruit`, it will be comparable to `Apple`, if an `Orange` implements `WeightedFruit`, it will be comparable to `Orange`, but not to each other.

You can not build a collection of "anything that is WeightedFruit", because they are not interchangeable - Apples and Oranges are different, because each is comparable to different kind.

Instead you want to do something like this:

```
use std::cmp::*;
use std::collections::*;

pub trait Fruit { }

pub trait WeightedFruit: Fruit {
    fn weight(&self) -> u32;
}

impl Ord for WeightedFruit {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.weight().cmp(&other.weight())
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for WeightedFruit {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl PartialEq for WeightedFruit {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.weight() == other.weight()
    }
}

impl Eq for WeightedFruit {}


struct Apple {
    weight: u32
}

impl Fruit for Apple {}

impl WeightedFruit for Apple {
    fn weight(&self) -> u32 {
        self.weight
    }
}

struct Orange {
    weight: u32
}

impl Fruit for Orange {}

impl WeightedFruit for Orange {
    fn weight(&self) -> u32 {
        self.weight
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let unsorted: LinkedList<Box<Fruit>> = LinkedList::new();
    let sorted: BTreeSet<Box<WeightedFruit>> = BTreeSet::new();
}
```

This says that every `WeightedFruit` fruit must be able to provide its `weight` and every `WeightedFruit` can be compared to any other `WeightedFruit` using this `weight`. Now you can make trait objects of `WeightedFruit` and mix them together in collections because they are interchangeable.

---

Additional explanation about the `Ord` and the `the trait ... cannot be made into an object` error:

When you work with trait objects, traits look kinda like interfaces in OO languages. You can have s trait and multiple structs that implement it and a function that takes a trait object. It can then call the functions of the trait on the object because it knows that it will have them and that they are exactly the same for every object. Just like in OO languages.

However traits have one extra feature: They can use the `Self` type in the function declarations. `Self` is always the type that implements the trait. If a trait uses the `Self` in any of its functions, it becomes special and can no longer be used as a trait object. Every time a struct implements such trait, it is implementing different version of it (a version where `Self` is different). You can not make a trait object because every struct that implements it is implementing different version of it.

The `Ord` in rust is like `Comparable<T>` in java, where `T` is selected for you by compiler. And just like you can not have a method that accepts anything `Comparable` in java (I hope you can not?), you can not have a method that accepts any `Ord` trait object.

Comment: I wish Rust documentation had examples and information like this. This is exactly what I tried to do. Thank you!